# Jquery function not working well after addClass

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable

When i run this code, the alert popup many times for `alertt()` function.

```
<script>
      var newdiv = '<div id="text2" onmouseover="alertt()" contenteditable="true">text color to be changed</div>';
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.addbutton').click(function () {
             $(this).after($(newdiv).addClass('e'));
         });
        $(".e").draggable({ }) .click(function() { 
              $(this).draggable({disabled: true}); })
                  .blur(function() { $(this).draggable({disabled: false});
                  alert('2');
                  });
    });
    function alertt() { 
        $(".e").draggable({ })
        .click(function() { 
            $(this).draggable({disabled: true});
            alert('3');
        })
        .blur(function() {
            $(this).draggable({disabled: false});
            alert('4');
        });
    }
      </script>
    <body>

    <div id="output"></div>
    <button class="addbutton">Add Text</button>
    <div id="text" class="e" contenteditable="true">text color to be changed</div>
    </body>
```

and why this function not working for new `<div>` even i was `addClass('e')` for this element.

```
$(".e").draggable({ }) .click(function() { 
                  $(this).draggable({disabled: true}); })
                      .blur(function() { $(this).draggable({disabled: false});
                      alert('2');
                      });
```

appreciate any suggestion or correction to solve this out.

Answer (score 0):

does not work because they are created dynamically and the click event is not attached to them. You must attach click event manual after create newDiv. Or unbind click event from all '.e' and bind again to all.